# Is this chip still usable?

Tags: connector, soldering, wire, rfid

[image: front]I tried soldering jumper wires to my [3-D antenna, CAS143-47](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Sumida%20PDFs/CAS143.pdf) and little bit of solder found it's way on the chip's body away from the pads.

[image: enter i[![back[![][4]]

It was my first attepmt at soldering. It looks ugly and wonder if it would still be usable?

I'm going to test it later this week, but now I'm just curious just how bad it looks from experienced person's standpoint?

Comment: I don't think it matters: What you have is an RF IC. I doubt it will work reliably with wires sticking out at all angles.

Comment: It probably does stil work.  You probably do not have the right product for cleaning flux, but cleaning does do wonders.

Comment: Given the low frequency you might barely get away with this as it, but it's almost certain you'll break it in handling, quite possibly breaking a connection right off the package in an unrepairable way.  If you really want to do this, you should find or create a suitable breakout board, possibly even by carving copper clad with a knife.  If you have to use wires, use something like 30 gauge silicone insulated hookup wire, and crimp pins on the far end if you must have those.

Comment: You've  already asked TWO questions about this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/459909/how-to-physically-connect-as3933-to-3d-antenna and  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/464510/how-to-connect-these-two-rf-components-on-a-prototype and only got into the present difficulty by disregarding the responses which you got there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to physically connect AS3933 to 3D antenna?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/459909/how-to-physically-connect-as3933-to-3d-antenna)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't have used the plug tips from the breadboard wires, but that shouldn't be a problem.

I've seen (and produced) worse looking solder joints that worked just fine.

I don't think you got it hot enough to disconnect things inside.  The datasheet shows the internal connections:

[image]

Use an ohmmeter and check the resistance between the pins.  Where the diagram shows a coil, you should measure a very low resistance.

I'd be more concerned about the two connections in the lower left corner.  They cross each other and I can't tell if they touch.

That is an RF antenna, but it is 125kHz so it isn't **that** demanding as far as wiring goes. Long wires aren't good for high frequencies.

I'd be more concerned about the fact you are using breadboard jumper wires.  That implies that you will be using a breadboard for your circuitry.  Breadboards have capacitance between rows and inductance in the rows.  Those can mess with high frequency signals - that might include your 125kHz, might not.

---

Looking at it closely, I don't quite see what you are doing with all the connections.

Depending on the orientation, either you have wires connected to pins with no internal connection or you have wires connected to just one end of a coil.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I understand that using jumper wires is not ideal in this situation but it was the cheapest solution available with my limited funds. I'm not sure about what you might've found confusing with the connections; I soldered the wires on all of the antennas pads. I added more pictures to the post where it shows both sides of the chip, just in case.