# Pad disconnected from smd chip

Tags: pcb, soldering, surface-mount, rfid

I was trying to breadboard a circuit using [3-D antenna chip](http://3D%20antenna%20chip). I didn't have pcb board ready for it so I tried to solder jumper wires on the pads and then test the circuit by breadboarding. 
[image]
After soldering one of the wires I noticed that it was attached very loosely to the pad and I gave it a little pull. The result was that chip's plate detached from chip's body. You can see in the second left from the bottom and bottom right.
[image]
I understand that soldering wires to the smd chip wasn't best idea but in absense of pcb it was the only choice. I'm wondering if there is a way to somehow fix this chip so I can still use it?

Comment: Um, what's a 3D antenna chip? your link seems to be not a link at all.

Comment: That could well be broken.  [See this answer for how to check if it is electrically OK.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/464508/47070)

Answer (score 4):

all these solder joints are bad; i.e. none of them looks like a good, reliable electrical connection. I'd recommend you practice a bit of your soldering, and maybe don't try to solder large metal pins on SMD pads, but if you need to do that, fine copper wire.

Seeing the thermal damage you did to the package, it's likely you fried whatever is inside.

Also, seeing the mechanical damage you did to the contacts, nope, I wouldn't assume the inside of this still works.

At RF frequencies (and this, I'm told, is a 125 kHz RFID "antenna", or rather half of a transformer), you might want to be a bit careful with the cable lengths you attach, as the conductors become part of the overall system if not designed appropriately.

Comment: That is a 125kHz RFID antenna.

Comment: @JRE I'll take the freedom to put "antenna" in quotation marks and call it a half-transformer, then? It's not meant to produce propagating waves, but to allow the other end to couple into reactive near field, as far as I understand.

Comment: Yep.  That's pretty much it.

Comment: @JRE yay! so, I'll remove the antenna part and highlight long cables aren't unproblematic